# What is the difference between had and got?

Tags: word-choice, past-participles, causative-verbs, get-passive

Are there any significant differences in uses or meanings between these two words? Between the two example sentences below, does one sentence have a slightly different meaning compared to the other, or are they fully interchangeable in all situations?

1. I **got** my hair cut.
2. I **had** my hair cut.

Comment: No, there are no significant differences in use or meaning between the two expressions _I got my hair cut_ and _I had my hair cut_. Both are ordinary English that any native speaker would use. Of course, every speaker makes choices and has habits, so individual usage will vary; but that's true of most grammatical choices.

Answer (score 1):

The two sentences are examples of *causative constructions*. Without further context they essentially mean the same in this case. But it cannot be claimed that *'they are fully interchangeable in all situations'*.

There is a section on the difference in meaning in *The Grammar Book: An ESL / EFL Teacher's Course* (p653):

> *Have*. The verb *have* suggests a routine hiring or selecting in which a relation of authority is implied, as between
> customer-businessperson or creditor-debtor:
>
> - We had Ray mow the lawn. (He does it every week.)
> - I had the barber trim my hair. (It is his profession.)
> - Fred had John give him $5. (It was part of the debt that John owed Fred.)
> - ?He had a stranger on the street give him directions.
>
> The questioned example above is inappropriate since it suggests a
> relation of authority which does not exist between two strangers in a
> chance meeting. The action performed must also relate to the specific
> *area* of authority.
>
> *Get*. The verb *get* often tends to convey the sense that some difficulty was involved; perhaps the subject of the main clause used
> persuasion or coercion on the subject of the embedded clause:
>
> - I got Ray to give me $5. (He had refused earlier.)
>
> Martin (1981)*, in a discourse analysis of causatives, provides
> support for the distinctions made above.  In one of his native speaker
> survey questionnaire items, 20 out of 23 respondents chose *get* when
> it was clear that some difficulty was involved:
>
> - I had a lot of trouble finding someone to do it, but I finally
>   (a) had the lawn mowed. (= 3) - (b) got the lawn mowed (= 20)

This [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20had%20my%20hair%20cut%2C%20I%20got%20my%20hair%20cut&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20had%20my%20hair%20cut%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20got%20my%20hair%20cut%3B%2Cc0) shows that *I had my hair cut* is more common than *I got my hair cut*, which supports the contention made in *The Grammar Book*. But, interestingly, it shows a significant increase in *I got my hair cut* over the last few decades.

So nobody is going to pull you up if you say *I got my hair cut*, particularly if some difficulty was involved. For example:

- After looking all day in town for a barber I finally got my hair cut at the airport just before departure.

Comment: *There is no bibliography in the  _The Grammar Book_ and I haven't been able to any references to Martin's analysis on the web. I'd be grateful if anyone can help out.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between the two is one of formality. *I **had** my hair cut* is (pretty much) always acceptable, whereas *I **got** my hair cut* is fairly informal.

In conversation I might use either, but **got** sounds less educated.

Reference: [Perfect English Grammar](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/causatives-have-get.html):

> We can also use 'subject + get + object + past participle'. This has the same meaning as 'have', but is less formal.

Answer (score 0):

Very often (especially in British English) both sentences are similar in meaning, though "to get" sounds more dynamic:

***To get smth done***

Reach or cause to reach a specified state or condition.

(with object and complement )

‘I need to get my hair cut’

(https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/get)

***To have smth done***

(with past participle)

Cause (something) to be done for one by someone else.

‘it is advisable to have your carpet laid by a professional’

(https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/have)

Here are some examples from Reverso.context.net:

I need to ***get*** my hair done.

So, Casey, I guess it's nice for you to ***get*** your hair cut.

Then I'll ***have*** my hair done.

Why don't you ***have*** your hair cut?